# Postgresql pattern matching

Tags: postgresql, design-patterns, matching

I want to get data in which `name` and `surname` start with 'Ib', but only `name` starts with 'Ib' in the resulting rows.

Here is my query:

```
select* 
from student
where concat(name,surname) like '%Ib';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're concatenating first name and surname, so you're checking if "name+surname" starts with "Ib". You want `where name like 'Ib%' AND surname like 'Ib%'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all rows where either name OR surname begin with "Ib":

```
select * 
from student
where name like '%Ib'
or surname like '%Ib';
```

If you want rows where they BOTH begin with "Ib":

```
select * 
from student
where name like '%Ib'
and surname like '%Ib';
```